# Getting groups list user Yammer Rest Services

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, yammer

Is there a REST service to get list of joined groups for a particular user? I am getting all the groups in the current network by using the service https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json (which is not documented the yammer API reference). But my requirement is the groups that the user had already joined. Any help given will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try it with the query string "mine" with a value of "1" : https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1